# Sysinternals Sysmon: How to log an unsuccessful TCP/IP connection attempt

Tags: windows, logging, tcpip

I would like to use Sysmon to log an unsuccessful TCP/IP connection attempt.

For example, with the following configuration:

```
<NetworkConnect onmatch="include">
 <DestinationPort condition="is">22</DestinationPort>
</NetworkConnect>
```

I do see a successful connection, such as

```
ssh user@existing.server.com
```

logged as

```
Network connection detected (rule: NetworkConnect)
```

However, if the handshake is not successful, e.g. because the attempt is dropped or reset, the attempt is not logged.

Is it possible to use Sysmon to log TCP/IP connection attempts?
If not, what would be a good way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try procmon (from sysinternal too) which log all activities of your server's process.
Or you can install netmonitor from microsoft which hrlp you to see you network traffic associated with yours processes.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. However, procmon uses (as far as I know) a proprietary, binary log file. Which makes it quite difficult to use procmon in combination with other tools in an automated, configurable manner.